# Explain why none of the lines through a point inside a hyperbola is a tangent line to that hyperbola?

Tags: calculus, geometry, projective-geometry

> Explain why none of the lines through a point inside a hyperbola is a tangent line to that hyperbola?

I'm thinking since points must be on the hyperbola in order to be tangent, then they can't be since they're inside the hyperbola.

Comment: Do you mean to write "is a tangent line to the hyperbola"?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry I think faster than I can type

Comment: The fact that **hyperbolas have asymptotes** is important here.

Comment: What is the *inside* of a hyperbola?

Comment: @Blue: not that much. The same holds for ellipses or parabolas, too.

Answer (score 3):

A hyperbola is given by a quadratic equation in $x$ and $y$, so assuming that a line $ax+by=c$ goes through a point on the hyperbola and it is also a tangent line to the hyperbola, there is a quadratic equation in $x$ (we get that by eliminating $y$) with three roots accounted with multiplicity. That obviously cannot happen, since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is an integral domain: any polynomial with degree $d$ has at most $d$ real roots accounted with multiplicity.

Everything changes dramatically if we consider an algebraic curve like
$$ y^2 = x^3+ax+b $$
over $\mathbb{C}$: in such a case *every* tangent line has to meet the curve at another point. In facts, that gives a group structure for an elliptic curve and a duplication formula.